# Attempting websocket communication with multiple browsers using Channels (Django) cannot be connected (message cannot be received)

Tags: python, django, websocket, channel

Using the Django (Python) library channels,
We have created a web service with a chat function.

Among them, using the function of consumer,
We have created a room to chat and a room list acquisition process.

When doing the acquisition of the room list (websocket communication) on the front end side, we can connect on one browser window, but we cannot get the room list with start up another browser or another account for chrome When trying to acquire the room list on the browser used, the connection of websocket (or receive after connection) is not processed properly.

I would like to acquire the room list from another browser as well,
Please teach the solution method.

---

**consumer.py**

```
class RoomListConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    groups = ['broadcast']

    async def connect(self):
        self.scope["session"].save()
        self.room = []
        self.room_group_name = "room_list" + self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['id']

        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            'room_list',
            self.channel_name
        )
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        self.scope["session"].save()
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            'room_list',
            self.channel_name
        )
        await self.close()

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        self.scope["session"].save()
        await self.setRoomList()
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
        self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'list': self.room
            }
        )

    async def chat_message(self, event):
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'type': 'chat_message',
            'list': self.room
        }))

    @database_sync_to_async
    def setRoomList(self):
    # Set Room List
```

---

**routing.py**

```
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^chat/list/(?P<id>[^/]+)/$', RoomListConsumer),
    url(r'^chat/(?P<id>[^/]+)/(?P<room_name>[^/]+)/$', ChatConsumer)
]

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

Comment: Did you give the error message in browser?

Comment: Thanks for the message.
No, I didn't give the error message in browser.

Comment: Then it means connecting to socket and sending message work well. I think you have to check receive func.

Comment: I'll check it. Thank you for reply.